# How do I delete all menu links from a menu using the menu machine name in Drupal 8

Tags: navigation

I trying to get the existing menu items and then delete them in bulk but I'm getting an error trying to load them.

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('menu_link')
->condition('menu_name', 'mycustommenu')
// Order by weight so as to be helpful for menus that are only one level deep.
->sort('weight');
$result = $query->execute();


Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "menu_link" entity type does not exist. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getDefinition() (line 125 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).
```

Can someone suggest how I might do this better thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$mids = \Drupal::entityQuery('menu_link_content')
  ->condition('menu_name', 'browse')
  ->sort('weight')
  ->execute();

$controller = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content');
$entities = $controller->loadMultiple($mids);
$controller->delete($entities);
```